# switching out a logo using jquery and bootstrap afix

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hey everyone thanks in advance for the help.

I know there are a lot of questions answered about this already but I feel like my problem has another layer. I'm using bootstraps affix command to make my nav bar sticky once it reaches the navbar at 300px. At this moment I'm also trying to get the navbar to switch out logos so I can display a smaller logo and not have to worry about such a large navbar. I think the problem lies in the navbar becoming fixed and throwing off my jquery scroll height. Please let me know if anyone has a fix for this.

Thanks!

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 300) {
      $("#logo").removeClass("site-logo-full"),
      $("#logo").addClass("site-logo-reduced");
    } else {
      $("#logo").removeClass("site-logo-reduced"),
      $("#logo").addClass("site-logo-full");
    }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<header class="jumbotron">

  <div class="container-fluid ad-container"> </div>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="300">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      </div>

      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li id="logo" class="hidden-xs site-logo-full">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-main-custom">
          <li><a href="#eventme">Event Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#events">Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  </section>

</header>
```

SASS

```
    // Jumbotron Css

.jumbotron
  background: url('../images/jumbotron.jpg') no-repeat center center
  height: 600px
  padding: 0

.ad-container
  height: 300px

.affix
  top: 0
  width: 100%
  z-index: 9999 !important

.affix ~ .container-fluid
  position: relative
  padding-top: 50px
```

And then I'm importing my images from WP functions.php

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'alpha_load_wp_head' ) ) {
    function alpha_load_wp_head() {
        // Get the logos
        $logo = IMAGES . '/logo.png';
        $logo_retina = IMAGES . '/logo@2x.png';

        $logo_size = getimagesize( $logo );
        ?>

        <!-- Logo CSS -->
        <style type="text/css">
            .site-logo-full a {
                background: url( <?php echo $logo; ?> ) 0 0 no-repeat;
                width: <?php echo $logo_size[0] ?>px;
                height: <?php echo $logo_size[1] ?>px;
                display: inline-block;
            }
```

Comment: What are the properties set on classes `.site-logo-full` and `.site-logo-reduced`... and are they being added/removed correctly?

Comment: I actually ended up figuring it out. I think the basic jquery that came with wp was conflicting with any scripts I wrote so I disabled the basic wp jquery script and uploaded the google jquery script.